# how to fetch data from firebase realtime database

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch data from firebase realtime database into my application when cast data object with pojo class im getting exception please help me

Here is data in json format which im trying to fetch from firebase it is json array which contains country names and radio station aaray in respective country

```
[ {
                  "country" : "india",
                  "station" : [ {
                    "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testing-radio-app.appspot.com/o/RadioUi%2F1.jpg?alt=media&token=1ff817e1-7caa-4074-927e-dfca0f7b49aa",
                    "title" : "India1",
                    "url" : "http://prclive1.listenon.in:9960"
                  }, {
                    "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testing-radio-app.appspot.com/o/RadioUi%2F2.jpg?alt=media&token=cb03a047-f51c-478d-8b0c-26379adba9a1",
                    "title" : "India2",
                    "url" : "http://192.240.102.133:11454/stream"
                  } ]
                }, {
                  "country" : "us",
                  "station" : [ {
                    "image" : "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/testing-radio-app.appspot.com/o/RadioUi%2Fmango.png?alt=media&token=ee11dcab-7ce4-4057-b045-2107b07bc97a",
                    "title" : "US1",
                    "url" : "http://7619.live.streamtheworld.com:3690/977_HITS_SC"
                  } ]
                } ]



                 **// here is my java code in side mainActivity here is firebase code**




  DatabaseReference database = 
 FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
                            database.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            **//here im getting all country array**
               Iterable<DataSnapshot> contact = dataSnapshot.getChildren();
                       for (DataSnapshot d:contact)
                                    {

            **//here im trying to read array data one by one and type cast it with pojo class but on this line im getting run time exception**
            Response res= d.getValue(Response.class);
                                        Log.d("data", "onDataChange: "+res.toString());

                                    }



                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });

                **these are my two pojo classes

                1.Station.java class contains radio station name, image, and url**

                    public class Station
                    {
                        private String image;

                        private String title;

                        private String url;

                        public String getImage ()
                        {
                            return image;
                        }

                        public void setImage (String image)
                        {
                            this.image = image;
                        }

                        public String getTitle ()
                        {
                            return title;
                        }

                        public void setTitle (String title)
                        {
                            this.title = title;
                        }

                        public String getUrl ()
                        {
                            return url;
                        }

                        public void setUrl (String url)
                        {
                            this.url = url;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String toString()
                        {
                            return "ClassPojo [image = "+image+", title = "+title+", url = "+url+"]";
                        }

                **2.Response.java class which contains conutry name and station array**

                    public class Response
                    {
                        private String country;

                        private Station[] station;

                        public String getCountry ()
                        {
                            return country;
                        }

                        public void setCountry (String country)
                        {
                            this.country = country;
                        }

                        public Station[] getStation ()
                        {
                            return station;
                        }

                        public void setStation (Station[] station)
                        {
                            this.station = station;
                        }

                        @Override
                        public String toString()
                        {
                            return "ClassPojo [country = "+country+", station = "+station+"]";
                        }
                    }
```

I'm geting this exception

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException:Converting to Arrays is not supported, please use Listsinstead

I want to fetch all country and its station data in single arrayList but because of this exception I'm not able to do it please help me . Thank you in advance

Comment: That is the exact exception that you get? Please add it to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the *station* **Array** to a **List** in Response.java as shown below.

```
public class Response
{
    private String country;

    private List<Station> station;

    public String getCountry ()
    {
        return country;
    }

    public void setCountry (String country)
    {
        this.country = country;
    }

    public List<Station> getStation ()
    {
        return station;
    }

    public void setStation (List<station> station)
    {
        this.station = station;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "ClassPojo [country = "+country+", station = "+station.toString()+"]";
    }
}
```